# Insert a number in a sorted list and return the list with the number at the correct index

Tags: python, sorting, recursion

I feel like the title is a bit wordy. What I have defined here is a function that takes two parameters:

- a list that contains valued sorted from smallest to biggest
- a number to insert at the right index so that the returned list print its values from smallest to biggest

**NOTE:** Recursion is mandatory

```
def insert(lst, to_insert):
    """
    parameters : lst of type list, that contains values sorted from smallest to largest;
                 to_insert : represents a value 
    returns : same list with the to_insert value positioned at the right index
              in order for the list to remain sorted from smallest to largest;
    """
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return []
    if lst[0] < to_insert and to_insert < lst[1]:
        lst[3] = to_insert
        return [lst[0]] + [lst[3]] + insert(lst[1:], to_insert)
    else:
        return [lst[0]] + insert(lst[1:], to_insert)

print(insert([1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9], 6))
```

The list outputs the following :

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]   #not sure where 9 got left
```

How do I optimize this function, using only simple functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if len(lst) == 1:
    return []
```

This is incorrect, as it crops one number off and produces the 9 bug you have seen. Instead, you can do:

```
if not lst:
    return [to_insert]
```

Similarly, the remaining of the function is overly complicated, and can return false results in some edge cases. You would have problems calling for `lst[3]` if the list is not of four elements or more, and I believe it's incorrect too when inserting `1` in `[2, 3, 4, 5]`.

```
if lst[0] > to_insert:
    return [to_insert] + lst
return [lst[0]] + insert(lst[1:], to_insert)
```

Would be more correct, although not optimal.

Comment: What does the line `return [to_insert] + lst` do?

Comment: @MisterTusk It returns the list prepended with the element to_insert. For example if to_insert is 1 and lst is [2, 3, 4], it will return [1, 2, 3, 4].

Answer (score 5):

Recursion is usually a poor choice in Python.  Non-tail recursion is usually a poor choice in any language (and this is non-tail because we apply `+` to the result before returning it).

It's better to use the standard `bisect` module to find (once) the correct index at which to insert.  This module provides the `bisect()` function to locate the correct index, and also the `insort()` function that calls `bisect` and then inserts, exactly as we want:

```
insert = bisect.insort
```

This will insert in place, rather than creating a new list, so not exactly equivalent to the existing code.

---

As you say *"using only simple functions"*, let's suppose you can't use the Standard Library (that's a bad assumption in general - Python philosophy is that it "includes batteries" to make your code simpler).  Then we can use a similar method to write our own non-recursive version.

```
def insert(lst, to_insert):
    """
    parameters : lst: sorted list (smallest to largest)
                 to_insert: value to add
    returns : copy of lst with the to_insert value added in sorted position
    """

    # binary search
    left = 0
    right = len(lst)

    while left != right:
        mid = left + (right-left) // 2
        if lst[mid] == to_insert:
            left = right = mid
        elif lst[mid] < to_insert:
            left = mid + 1
        else:
            right = mid

    # now copy the list, inserting new element
    return lst[:left] + [to_insert] + lst[left:]
```

---

Since the question states (without justification) that "recursion is mandatory", I recommend making the search recursive, but performing the insertion just once:

```
#! untested
def insert(lst, to_insert, left=0, right=None):
    if right is None:
        right = len(lst)

    if left == right:
        return lst[:left] + [to_insert] + lst[left:]

    else:
        mid = left + (right-left) // 2
        if lst[mid] == to_insert:
            left = right = mid
        elif lst[mid] < to_insert:
            left = mid + 1
        else:
            right = mid
        # move left or right, then
        return insert(lst, to_insert, left, right)
```

This is now tail-recursive, at least, and only reallocates the list elements once, rather than every level of recursion.

Comment: I suppose this is a programming exercise.

Comment: Could be - that said, looking at how they work might be instructive.